# Jest - test a dynamic import failing

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, dynamic-import

I have a React component with dynamic imports, and a Jest/Enzyme test which is checking what happens if one of those imports errors. I am having an issue where Jest fails the test because of the error I am throwing, and I can't seem to get it to pass even using `expect().toThrow()`

I'm not sure what I should be doing here... Ideally I would like a way to tell Jest just to ignore any errors.

Inside component:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  try {
    // there are more things in real component and so that is why Promise.all
    const [Card] = await Promise.all([
      import(
        /* webpackChunkName:"@Card" */ './index'
      )
    ]);
    this.setState({ Card });
  } catch(e) {
  }
}

render() {
  const { Card } = this.state;
  if (Card) { ... }
  else { ... }
}
```

Test:

```
jest.mock('../../card', () => {
  throw new Error('Forcing async import error');
});
const wrapper = mount(<MyComp {...props} />);
expect(wrapper.find('Loading').prop('dimensions')).toEqual(props.dimensions);
```

Comment: Can you include your entire component source? Right now, I don't see where (or if) you're catching your promises.

Comment: Sorry, I updated it to show the try/catch that is there. If I add a console.log in the catch block in componentDidMount it does log the error. There is quite a lot going on in the component so I can't really paste the whole thing.

Comment: Are you setting the imports to state or doing something else? In addition, your `Card` import is essentially a promise and you're mocking it as callback function that just throws an error. You can try creating a promise and rejecting it with the error.

Comment: Yeah essentially, the imported file is another React component, it gets passed into an HOC and then the result from that is saved to the state. The render function checks for that in the state and renders it if it exists - I updated the code example to show more-or-less what I'm doing

Comment: Interesting. After some research it looks like enzyme doesn't resolve the dynamic mock properly. If I pass a simple string, like `default: "p"`, then it works as expected (by returning a `<p />` component). However, if I wrap it in a `Promise` or utilize a `Promise` within the `default` export, it's not being resolved. It appears like this issue has been brought up several times: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1460, https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/2212, and https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/2200